# Validation without UpdateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a an ASP.NET MVC2 application, with Linq2SQL, that updates a database without using the UpdateModel. Is it still possible to trigger validation without using UpdateModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is built into the default model binder. So there is no need to call UpdateModel or anything else to trigger the validation.

Comment: I have a custom validation using data annotations with a buddy class. This only triggers when I call UpdateModel.

Comment: @Danny, Can you please show your code? The only thing UpdateModel does is use the model binder and the binder itself handles the validation. So there shouldn't be any difference.